# IntersectionObserver works incorrectly when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
let isFooterVisible = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > $('.btn').offset().top && isFooterVisible === false) {
    $('.btn').addClass("fixed");
  } else {
    $('.btn').removeClass("fixed");
  }
});
function isIntoView(entries, obs){
  entries.forEach(entry => {
     if (entry.target.id === 'end'){
       if (entry.isIntersecting === true){
         isFooterVisible = true;
         $('.btn').removeClass("fixed");
       }
       else{
         isFooterVisible = false;
       }
     } 
  });
}
let options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(isIntoView, options);
let target = $('#end')[0];
observer.observe(target);
```

```css
.info {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="btn">button</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info" id="end">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
```

I want to make sure that at the moment of scrolling to a specific element, it is fixed on the page and is all the time when scrolling down, and until the moment of crossing another class, it is hidden.

I wrote this code, everything seems to be working, it appears and hides where it is needed, but when the page is scrolled, this fixed element lags wildly.

What could be the problem??

Comment: (Offtopic) Doing `$('.btn')` two times inside a `"scroll"` Event is a total performance killer. Cache that `$('.btn')` inside a variable beforehand!

Comment: If I got your question correctly... perhaps you don't need JavaScript at all... But I'm not sure about the final desired result you have in mind?!

Comment: When asking, don't just use words like *" it is fixed"*. *It* who? Be more specific, don't force the reader to go through the entire code to understand your thoughts. Please read: [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: *" it is hidden"* but you don't use any means of hiding anything...